# Dynamic treeview using linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I want help from u i am developing a website for my final sem.I want to develop dynamic treeview using linq .If any buddy have sample for this pls help me.

Comment: Did you try anything? Code? Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

this is a good and simple sample. try it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/12/31/treeview-datasource-for-linq-to-entities-versus-a-sql-command-in-code-behind-versus-code-in-front.aspx